# React: Mute/Unmute youtube embed player without re-rendering the entire component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, youtube-iframe-api

I've created a web app (using React Js) which shows youtube video inside a player using [react-youtube](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-youtube) npm package.

'props' passed to this component = `{ youtubeVideoId, streetSound, playbackSpeed }`

YoutubePlayer.js Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import YouTube from 'react-youtube';
import './style.css';

class YoutubePlayer extends React.Component {

onReady = (event) => {
    event.target.setPlaybackRate(this.props.playbackSpeed);
    event.target.playVideo();
}

render() {
    const opts = {
        playerVars: {
            autoplay: 1,
            mute: this.props.streetSound ? 0 : 1,
            modestbranding: 1,
            autohide: 1,
            showinfo: 0,
            controls: 0,
            playbackSpeed: this.props.playbackSpeed
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className='containerStyle'>

            <YouTube
                videoId={this.props.youtubeVideoId} 
                opts={opts}
                onReady={this.onReady}
                onStateChange={this.onStateChange}
                className='videoPlayerStyle'
            />

            {/* Prevents clicks on youtube player */}
            <div className='overlayStyle' />
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default YoutubePlayer;
```

How can I dynamically mute/unmute the video without re-rendering the whole component?

Comment: Would be good if you create this in `codesandbox.io` so it can be replicated/tested. But you should be able to use refs https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html. That should give access to DOM

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), see this issue: https://github.com/tjallingt/react-youtube/issues/211